# ASP.Net - Telerik Compatible with master page(<meta.. content="IE=9")

Tags: telerik

I'm using in my website some of the Telerik controls. (framework 2)  Now i need to change the meta line to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

instead of:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

For css compabilty(for border radius and other things), when i change this line, the telerik controls in some pages are not looking good.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Might be better posting on the Telerik forum - my guess is you are using a older build before IE9 support was added - try getting the latest version and give it another go.

Comment: What version of controls are these?  What do you mean by framework 2, as in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Because the stylesheet streamed out from Telerik.Web.Resource.axd handler does not set the mime type properly and IE9 ignores stylesheets without proper mimetype set.

I am not aware of any solution for it except adding the IE7 compatibility meta tag.

**Solution:**
Create a new code file and add the embedded stylesheets with the assembly code as below.

```
[assembly: WebResource("Assets.Skins.Calendar.Custom.css", "text/css")]
```